# request = self.context.get('request') , give me'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I'm trying to exclude certain fields from being displayed in the list view of my serializer. To achieve this, I have overridden the `to_representation` method.
However, when I attempt to access the 'request' object using `request = self.context.get('request')`,
I encountered an error stating "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'.

this is serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from todo.models import Task

class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    short_content=serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='get_short_content')
    
    author = serializers.CharField(source="author.username", read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields =['id','title', 'author' ,'details' ,'short_content','isCompleted','created_date','updated_date']
        read_only_fields=['author']


  
   def to_representation(self,instance):
        request=self.context.get('request')
        rep =super().to_representation(instance)
        print(request.data)
        if request.parser_context.get('kwargs').get('pk'):
            rep.pop('short_content',None)
            
        else:
            rep.pop('details',None)
        return rep
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework import generics

from todo.models import Task
from .serializers import TodoSerializer



class TaskListViewSets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated]
    queryset=Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class=TodoSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Task.objects.filter(author=self.request.user.id)

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset().filter(author=request.user)
        serializer = TodoSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def perform_create(self,serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

Any insights into why I might be receiving this error and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you also update your view as well?

Comment: No, if I add the to_representation I can't see anything give me an error.
I write the print(request. data), and it gives me the top error.

Comment: I mean to update your question with views.py contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are implementing *too much* boilerplate, the list will work with a serializer with the right context:

```
from rest_framework import generics, viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from todo.models import Task

from .serializers import TodoSerializer


class TaskListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Task.objects.filter(author=self.request.user.id)

    # no list method, this is implemented with the right serializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```